# Objective-C class identifiers are prefixed with objc_class_ instead of _OBJC_CLASS_$_

Tags: ios, objective-c, arm, reverse-engineering, method-swizzling

I'm trying to swizzle some methods in an application made with Objective-C. I'm getting this error:

```
Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_IASAvatarViewController
```

After opening the executable in Hopper, I see that all of the classes are prefixed with `objc_class_` instead. So the class name of the method I'm trying to swizzle is `objc_class_IASAvatarViewController`. First off, I'm dying to know how the class identifiers have turned out that way (some sort of name mangling?). And second, I'd like to know if it's possible to have my dylib reference the correct identifier.

DylibTest.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@interface IASBaseViewController : UIViewController

@end

@interface IASAvatarViewController : IASBaseViewController

@end

@interface IASAvatarViewController (Swizzle)

@end
```

DylibTest.m

```
#import "DylibTest.h"
#import <dlfcn.h>

@implementation IASAvatarViewController (Swizzle)

+ (void)load {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        Class class = [self class];

        SEL originalSelector = @selector(viewDidLoad);
        SEL swizzledSelector = @selector(xxx_viewDidLoad);

        Method originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, originalSelector);
        Method swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, swizzledSelector);

        BOOL didAddMethod =
        class_addMethod(class,
                    originalSelector,
                    method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod),
                    method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod));

        if (didAddMethod) {
            class_replaceMethod(class,
                            swizzledSelector,
                            method_getImplementation(originalMethod),
                            method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod));
        } else {
            method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod);
        }
    });
 }


 - (void)xxx_viewDidLoad {
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Swizzled method" message:@"Ya swizzle" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Yeah. Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];

    [self xxx_viewDidLoad];
 }

 @end
```

And a screen shot of Hopper with the Objective-C classes:
[image: Screen shot of Hopper]

**Edit:** Got enough reputation to directly post image.

**Edit2:** [`class-dump`](http://stevenygard.com/projects/class-dump/) of the file: http://pastebin.com/DcUD5AL5

Comment: I had no idea swizzling was an actual term before seeing this question. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, yeah! I had some problems finding out how to do this at first, because I was was looking for "interposing," which you do in C/C++. Took me a while to figure out the "equivalent" in Obj-C is "swizzling."

Comment: Swizzling happens at run-time, after the application has loaded and is executing.  Your error is occurring long before that, so it's unlikely that swizzling is the cause of the problem.  I presume you have no @implementation of `IASAvatarViewController`, which causes the linker/loader error.

Comment: No, I don't have that implementation. It's not my own application...

Comment: The implementation for `IASAvatarViewController` doesn't exist.  That's what the loader error is telling you.

Comment: Well, I know that's what it's telling me, but obviously it must exist somewhere?

Comment: It's not at all obvious that `IASAvatarViewController` must exist somewhere.  From what you've posted, I think it does not.

Comment: Using `class-dump`, shows that there is a class called `IASAvatarViewController`. I've tried swizzling other classes instead, but none of them seems to "exist" to my Dynamic Library. Is it possible that it is compiled with another compiler or with some sort of compiler flag?